# Quero sortear um numero aleatório e compara-lo com um numero do index do array

Tags: javascript, json

Olá , estou tentando fazer um banco de questões utilizando JSON, mas o grande desafio no momento é aleatorizar minhas questões. Eu sei mais ou menos a logica mas não consigo aplica-lá, gostaria de sortear minhas perguntas, comparando o index do array delas com o numero aleatorio sorteado e assim mostrar essa pergunta do index no o meu content com essa questão do JSON. Se puderem me ajudar a construir essa logica ou a mostrar um caminho ficarei agradecido !

```js
const catchQuest = document.getElementById("paragraph").value;
let randomQuestion;

function loadJSON() {
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.open("get", "./../json/quiz.json");

  request.onload = () => {
    try {
      const json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
      displayResult(json);
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn("Could not load JSON ");
    }
  };
  request.send();
}

function displayResult(json) {
//    console.log(json.banco_questoes[1]); 
  randomQuestion = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
//   console.log(randomQuestion);

if (randomQuestion === json.banco_questoes.indeOf(i)) {
    // Substitui o o paragrafo do HTML pela pergunta 
}


}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  loadJSON();
});
```

```css
/**************************************Reset-code-Start***********************************************************/
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline; }

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block; }

body {
  line-height: 1; }

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none; }

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none; }

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: "";
  content: none; }

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0; }

/**************************************Reset-code-end***********************************************************/
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gilroy';
  src: url("./../font/Gilroy-Black.woff2") format("woff2"), url("./../font/Gilroy-Black.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: normal; }

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gilroy';
  src: url("./../font/Gilroy-Regular.woff2") format("woff2"), url("./../font/Gilroy-Regular.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal; }

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gilroy';
  src: url("./../font/Gilroy-Light.woff2") format("woff2"), url("./../font/Gilroy-Light.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal; }

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gilroy';
  src: url("./../font/Gilroy-ExtraBold.woff2") format("woff2"), url("./../font/Gilroy-ExtraBold.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: 800;
  font-style: normal; }

.intro-body {
  background: url("./../img-compressed/img/bg2.png"); }

.client {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: 50px 50px 50px 50px; }
  .client img {
    margin-right: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px; }

.indicator {
  width: 300px;
  height: 120px;
  background: #e91b30;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px; }

ul {
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Gilroy";
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 6px; }
  ul li {
    line-height: 19px; }

.progress-bar-1 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 55px;
  left: 110px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 20px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 6px; }

.progress-bar-2 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 28px;
  left: 110px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 20px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 6px; }

.place-holder {
  margin: 100px; }

.btn-continue {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  left: 395px;
  bottom: 140px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: "Gilroy";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: bold;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border-block-style: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f43b47 0%, #453a94 100%); }

.btn-continue:active {
  transform: translateY(6px); }

.game-rule {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: 33% 33% 33%;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 550px;
  height: 400px;
  top: 425px;
  left: 25px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: "Gilroy";
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-style: bold;
  justify-self: center;
  color: white;
  line-height: 30px;
  gap: 10px; }

.progress-bar-fill-1, .progress-bar-fill-2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3.5px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 13px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 6px; }

.game-body {
  background: url("./../img-compressed/img/bg3.png"); }

.img {
  max-width: 50%;
  max-height: 70%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 25%;
  bottom: 10%; }

.question-window .question {
  background-color: white;
  width: 60%;
  height: 450px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  border-radius: 30px; }

.question-window .question::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  bottom: -15px;
  border: white 2px solid;
  border-radius: 30px; }

.question-window p {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: "Gilroy";
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  top: 30px; }

/*
=====
LEVEL 1. CORE STYLES
=====
*/
.toggle {
  --uiToggleSize: var(--toggleSize, 20px);
  --uiToggleIndent: var(--toggleIndent, 0.4em);
  --uiToggleBorderWidth: var(--toggleBorderWidth, 2px);
  --uiToggleColor: var(--toggleColor, #000);
  --uiToggleDisabledColor: var(--toggleDisabledColor, #868e96);
  --uiToggleBgColor: var(--toggleBgColor, #fff);
  --uiToggleArrowWidth: var(--toggleArrowWidth, 2px);
  --uiToggleArrowColor: var(--toggleArrowColor, #fff);
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative; }

.toggle__input {
  position: absolute;
  left: -99999px; }

.toggle__label {
  display: inline-flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  min-height: var(--uiToggleSize);
  padding-left: calc(var(--uiToggleSize) + var(--uiToggleIndent)); }

.toggle__label:before,
.toggle__label:after {
  content: "";
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  font-size: var(--uiToggleSize);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0; }

.toggle__label:before {
  border: var(--uiToggleBorderWidth) solid var(--uiToggleColor);
  z-index: 2; }

.toggle__input:disabled ~ .toggle__label:before {
  border-color: var(--uiToggleDisabledColor); }

.toggle__input:focus ~ .toggle__label:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px var(--uiToggleBgColor), 0 0 0px 4px var(--uiToggleColor); }

.toggle__input:not(:disabled):checked:focus ~ .toggle__label:after {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px var(--uiToggleBgColor), 0 0 0px 4px var(--uiToggleColor); }

.toggle__input:not(:disabled) ~ .toggle__label:after {
  background-color: var(--uiToggleColor);
  opacity: 0; }

.toggle__input:not(:disabled):checked ~ .toggle__label:after {
  opacity: 1; }

.toggle__text {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto; }

/*
  The arrow size and position depends from sizes of square because I needed an arrow correct positioning from the top left corner of the element toggle
  */
.toggle__text:before {
  content: "";
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  font-size: var(--uiToggleSize);
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-color: var(--uiToggleArrowColor);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5428em;
  left: 0.2em;
  z-index: 3;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: rotate(-40deg) skew(10deg); }

.toggle__input:not(:disabled):checked ~ .toggle__label .toggle__text:before {
  width: 0.5em;
  height: 0.25em;
  border-left-width: var(--uiToggleArrowWidth);
  border-bottom-width: var(--uiToggleArrowWidth);
  will-change: width, height;
  transition: width 0.1s ease-out 0.2s, height 0.2s ease-out; }

.toggle__label:before,
.toggle__label:after {
  border-radius: 2px; }

/* 
  The animation of switching states
  */
.toggle__input:not(:disabled) ~ .toggle__label:before,
.toggle__input:not(:disabled) ~ .toggle__label:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform-origin: center center;
  will-change: transform;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-out; }

.toggle__input:not(:disabled) ~ .toggle__label:before {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transition-delay: 0.2s; }

.toggle__input:not(:disabled) ~ .toggle__label:after {
  transform: rotateY(90deg); }

.toggle__input:not(:disabled):checked ~ .toggle__label:before {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  transition-delay: 0s; }

.toggle__input:not(:disabled):checked ~ .toggle__label:after {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transition-delay: 0.2s; }

.toggle__text:before {
  opacity: 0; }

.toggle__input:not(:disabled):checked ~ .toggle__label .toggle__text:before {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.1s ease-out 0.3s, width 0.1s ease-out 0.5s,
 height 0.2s ease-out 0.3s; }

.toggle {
  --toggleColor: #690e90;
  --toggleBgColor: #9b59b6;
  --toggleSize: 50px; }

.page {
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  order: 1; }

.page__toggle {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: black;
  font-family: "Gilroy";
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-style: bold; }

.page__toggle:nth-child(n + 2) {
  margin-top: 50px; }

.btn-confirm {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  left: 750px;
  top: 510px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: "Gilroy";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: bold;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border-block-style: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f43b47 0%, #453a94 100%); }

.result-body {
  background: url("./../img-compressed/img/bg4_gray.png"); }

.result-window .result {
  background-color: #e91b30;
  width: 50%;
  height: 550px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 30px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto; }

.result-window .result::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  bottom: -15px;
  border: #bd1728 2px solid;
  border-radius: 30px; }

.result-window p {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: "Gilroy";
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  top: 30px; }

.result-window img {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 30px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 30px 40px auto; }

.result-window span {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 30px;
  top: 30px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 200px;
  right: 0;
  margin: 30px 40px auto;
  font-family: "Gilroy";
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  color: white; }

.result-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 30px;
  top: 450px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 500px;
  right: 0;
  width: 40%;
  height: 10%;
  margin: 30px 40px auto;
  line-height: 30px; }
  .result-indicator ul {
    font-family: "Gilroy";
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left; }

.space {
  position: relative;
  left: 85px; }

.progress-bar-result-1 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 70px;
  left: 115px;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 6px; }

.new-progress-bar-fill-1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 7px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 15px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 6px; }

.new-progress-bar-fill-2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 7px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 15px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 6px; }

.progress-bar-result-2 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 40px;
  left: 210px;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 6px; }

img {
  filter: blur(1px); }

article {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  top: 50%;
  font-size: 1.9em;
  font-family: "Gilroy";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 33px;
  padding: 5px auto; }
  article h2 {
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    font-family: "Gilroy";
    font-weight: 800;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #75308a; }
  article span {
    font-family: "Gilroy";
    font-weight: 800;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #cb2031; }

.btn-challenge {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  height: 10%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  bottom: -50px;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-family: "Gilroy";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: bold;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border-block-style: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f43b47 0%, #453a94 100%); }

.btn-challenge:active {
  transform: translateY(6px); }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body class="game-body">
    <div>
      <div class="client">
        <img src="./img-compressed/img/arte_indicadores.png" alt="" />
        <div class="indicator">
          <ul>
            <li class="satisfaction">
              Satisfação <br />
              do Cliente
            </li>
            <br />
            <li>Fidelização</li>
          </ul>
          <div class="progress-bar-1">
            <div class="progress-bar-fill-1"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="progress-bar-2">
            <div class="progress-bar-fill-2"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <img
        src="./img-compressed/img/arte_quiz.png"
        alt="art-quiz"
        class="img"
      />

      <div class="question-window">
        <div class="question">
          <p class="questions" id="paragraph">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ut
            urna velit. Nam quis ?
          </p>
          <div class="page">
            <div class="page__toggle">
              <label class="toggle">
                <input class="toggle__input" type="checkbox" checked />
                <span class="toggle__label">
                  <span class="toggle__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
                </span>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="page__toggle">
              <label class="toggle">
                <input class="toggle__input" type="checkbox" />
                <span class="toggle__label">
                  <span class="toggle__text">consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
                </span>
              </label>
            </div>

            <div class="page__toggle">
              <label class="toggle">
                <input class="toggle__input" type="checkbox" hint="" />
                <span class="toggle__label">
                  <span class="toggle__text">Vivamus ut urna velit.</span>
                </span>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      
          <button class="btn-confirm" href="game-page.html" onclick="location.href = './page-result.html';" >CONTINUAR</button>
       
      </div>
    </div>
   
    <script src="./js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma vez que você tenha carregado o JSON, que assumirei que é uma lista de objetos, basta escolher um item aleatório entre essa lista.

Algo assim:

```js
// Após carregar, você terá algo assim:
const json = [
  { id: 'A' },
  { id: 'B' },
  { id: 'C' },
  { id: 'D' },
  { id: 'E' }
];

// Escolhe um item aleatório:
const item = json[Math.floor(Math.random() * json.length)];

// Selecionamos o elemento e inserimos o texto nele.
const content = document.querySelector('#content');
content.textContent = item.id;
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```